# Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.entrySet()" because "contextMap" is null

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, smtp

I'm trying to run my own simple smtp server using subethamail

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener(new EmailContentService());

    SMTPServer smtpServer = new SMTPServer(
                                new SimpleMessageListenerAdapter(messageListener));
    smtpServer.setPort(12110);
    //starting SMTP server
    smtpServer.start();
}
```

Server is running, but when I try to send an email to the server this Exception shows up:

Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.entrySet()" because "contextMap" is null
at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jMDCAdapter.setContextMap(Log4jMDCAdapter.java:78)
at org.slf4j.MDC.setContextMap(MDC.java:205)    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Does anyone know where the problem is? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: maybe you use old slf4j/ subethasmtp ?!
see https://giters.com/davidmoten/subethasmtp/issues/13